# Eventos al iniciar y/o cerrar una sesión en Laravel

Tags: login, laravel-8, sesiones

necesito disparar eventos cuando un usuario inicializa un sesión bajo Laravel, cuando la cierra o bien cuando se vence el tiempo de vida de dicha sesión. El motivo por el cual necesito hacer esto es que debo identificar desde un Panel de Control, que usuarios tienen una sesión activa en el sitio. Revisando en otros post, se sugiere utilizar eventos y de ahí surge esta idea de implementación, pero si ustedes han implementado esto por otra vía o Laravel mismo ya tiene algún comando mágico que se pueda usar, les estaré muy agradecido por la data. Pido disculpas por no aportar código para vuestra revisión debido a que aún no he comenzado y me encuentro en etapa de revisión de alternativas.

Desde ya, muchas gracias y gran saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno esto yo lo hice (debe haber mejores formas lo sé) con la cache de laravel.

Primero tienes que crearte un middleware en mi caso LastUserActity y en el handle

```
      if(Auth::check()) {
        $expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(1);
        \Cache::put('user-is-online-' . Auth::user()->id, true,$expiresAt);
    }
    return $next($request);
```

en mi caso solo le doy un minuto de vida y cada que el usuario recarga una pagina se vuelve a crear

Lo registras en el kernel.php middlewareGroups

```
       \App\Http\Middleware\LastUserActivity::class,
```

y en tu modelo usuarios agregas lo siguiente

```
public function isOnline()
{
    return Cache::has('user-is-online-' . $this->id);
}
```

y ahora si quieres saber si un usuario esta en linea solo tienes que hacer

```
if($user->isOnline()){Hacer algo}
```

Para obtener el listado se podría hacer de la siguiente forma

```
$users=usuarios_model::all()->filter(function($user){
  if($user->isOnline())
  return $user;
});
```

Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Ok, entiendo la idea, pero lo que necesito es mostrar en una lista todos los usuarios que están activos, es decir, al momento de ingresar al Panel de Control, necesito ver a todos los usuarios que en ese momento están conectados. Por eso pensaba en los eventos al iniciar y cerrar sesión. También me estaría faltando el evento que se dispara cuando la sesión caduca porque el usuario no tuvo mas actividad en el sitio.

Comment: @RenéMerlo actualice la respuesta esa es una opción para obtener el listado